# C#, подключение к другому компьютеру (авторизация)

Tags: авторизация

Срочно нужна консультация по C# (.Net).
Нужно из программы подключиться к другому компьютеру (считать журнал событий EventLog), и не знаю, как сообщить этому другому компьютеру имя пользователя и пароль (они не такие, как на моём, их нужно сообщить через программу).
Кто подскажет, как это сделать?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что этот сайт не является бесплатной консультацией по срочным и к тому же плохо сформулированным вопросам.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы выложите код то можно будет ответить более предметно, в целом надо передавать стандартно для Win в формате **.\Username**